# Is there a word for when you tell show something and it doesn't work?

Tags: idioms, popular-refrains

E.g. "This hasn't been working all day", and then when you show it, it works

Comment: Many years ago I read a description of this called something like "mechanic's syndrome", where your car acted up until you drove to the mechanic's to get it fixed.  Then it would suddenly start acting fine.

Comment: *Light at the end of the tunnel*? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/light-at-the-end-of-the-tunnel?topic=hoping-and-hopefulness

Comment: *Blessing in disguise*?

Comment: If you can clean this up a little I got an answer (maybe). The title is confusing, and possibly you could flesh out the context.

Comment: It's an example of the operation of "Sod's Law" which states that 'what can go wrong will go wrong'. Unfortunately it also means that when it has gone wrong it will start to work again whenever it is most embarrassing!

Comment: @BoldBen In the US we call that Murphy's Law.

Comment: @Barmar So do we if we're being polite (or politically incorrect). You can't win these days!